# LINQtoSQL , repository pattern and lazy load

Tags: linq-to-sql, repository, repository-pattern

How do you use LINQtoSQL with the repository pattern?

I’m new to L2S and find its lazy loading to be a real impediment to using  the repo pattern.

Usually, I think of the repository pattern like this:

```
var myCustomer = null;

using (var myRepo = new Repo()){
    myCustomer = myRepo.GetCustomerForCustomerId(123);
}

if(myCustomer.Orders.Any()){
 //do something
}
```

Trouble is, won’t L2S attempt to make a data connection when myCustomer.Orders is interrogated?  Doesn’t this lead to unpredicatable database access issues?

I mean, yes, I could tell my repo to verify orders inside of the repo confident that our complete test coverage verifies that developers never call an entity we didn't explicitly load, but I would rather just get rid of the lazy loading/object-datacontext persistence.

So I have 4 options

1. Create domain objects that get created from the L2S objects – lots of work and maintainance
2. Create derived verisons of my L2S object that break he linkage (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq-to-sql-detach.aspx)
3. Use LLBLGenPro instead.
4. Appeal to the wisdom of stack overflow readers

I’m going with 4 for now.

**How do I ensure that my objects wont call the db after my repo is closed?**

And yes, I did read every stack question that talks about L2S and Repos and none of them answer this question.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my impression is that L2S or any other language layer often scares more than solving problems. Some people (myself included) feel annoyed by not knowing what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: @vulkanino, only someone who hasn't used L2S could say something like that.  What do you prefer, raw SQL?

Comment: yes, raw sql in the db's stored procedures, indeed. no sql code in the program sources.

Comment: I'm committed to using some ORM tool.  Having used one in the past, I would never go back to sprocs and SQL commands.  I'm just interested in figuring out if and how L2S can give me the control that I had when I used LLBLGenPro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it *is* useful to eager-load an entity's children.  You can do so with [DataLoadOptions.LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx) which tells your DataContext to automatically load an entity's children when the parent entity is loaded.

Snippet from the [MSDN link above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx):

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders);
db.LoadOptions = dlo
```

You can also use [DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534221.aspx) to further customize the behavior of the automatic loading.